# How to Separate Router from Controller in Express App?

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I want to separate routes from controller.

I tried this approach:

**routes/index.js**

```
var express              = require('express');
var router               = express.Router();
var wordMapperController = require('../controller/wordmapper');

router.get('/', wordMapperController());

module.exports = router;
```

**controller/wordmapper.js**

```
var __construct = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Word Mapping for Sanskrit-Indonesian in BG' });

    next();
}

module.exports = __construct;
```

When I start the res is undefined, and prevent the app to be launched.
How does I handle this? How is it app.use and handle router middleware being passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you're getting `res` is `undefined` is because you're calling the `wordMapperController` function and then passing what it returns (in this case undefined, since you don't return anything) as the callback to the `router.get` method...

This is what you should be doing instead:

**routes/index.js**

```js
router.get('/', wordMapperController);
```

Also, there's no reason to call `next()` in your `controller/wordmapper.js` file...

From the `express.js` documentation:

> If the current middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.

In your case, you're ending your request-response cycle with the `res.render` method invocation, therefore you should only be doing this:

**controller/wordmapper.js**

```js
var __construct = function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Word Mapping for Sanskrit-Indonesian in BG' 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was my bad, I was invocating the function instead of returning the object.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing good. But small changes will make your application looks perfect. Find them below.

1. Change the line "**router.get('/', wordMapperController())**"  to
   "**router.get('/', wordMapperController)**" - because when hits the route "/", it 
   will calls the middle ware function in the controller by passing request, response 
   and next as parameters;
2. If you want to render a template, you have to set the template engine server file - 
   for eg: app.set('view engine', 'pug') (if it is a .pug file);
3. Let me know if you get any issues while doing the above.

For reference, You can go through this link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/routes

Thank you.